# Node.js version warning locking out the command line

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, command-line

After a recent system update, when I open the terminal, there is a warning about this current version of Node.js that displays in the terminal window, but never resolves to the command line prompt.

How can I get my command line prompt back?  Screenshot below:

[image]

I've tried the obvious things like Ctrl+C, reinstalling as well as rolling back Node.js (blocked due to dependencies).  I've tried using other command line interface applications and they have the same issue.  Oddly enough, only the terminal in VSCode gets back to the prompt.

Comment: What system are you using?  What terminal?

Comment: I'm using an arch-based linux distro